# How to access the elapsed time of VLC when paused? - Java subtitle strings parsing program

Tags: java, open-source, vlc, playback, string-parsing

I'm writing a **java program** dealing with parsing text from a subtitle file.

The idea is, whenever I come across a word in the subtitles that I dont know while playing a movie, *I pause the video* and *open my client*, then the client *accesses the elapsed time*, *gets the sentence* and *displays the meanings* of all the words in that sentence using some offline dictionary.

I just want to "**get the elaspsed time at that instant**" - which I think is really basic thing, so I dont want to go through all the documentations of VLC (I tried but I felt like they were too complex and I have no interest in further contributing to VLC open source)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script in AutoHotkey that can retrieve the elapsed time and duration from VLC,
via Microsoft Active Accessibility (MSAA).

```
^q::
WinGet, hWnd, ID, ahk_class QWidget ahk_exe vlc.exe
oAcc := Acc_Get("Object", "4.3.3", 0, "ahk_id " hWnd)
vText := oAcc.accChild(1).accName(0) " / " oAcc.accChild(3).accName(0)
oAcc := ""
MsgBox % vText
Return
```

You launch the script via Ctrl+Q, and it will output the time in a MsgBox.
You can use `FileRead` and `Loop, Parse` to find the matching point
in a subtitles .srt file for example. Or you could for example append the timestamp to a .txt file using `FileAppend` and then read that into Java.

To use it:

You install AutoHotkey, maximum around 5 MB of space,
save the script as a .ahk file and double-click the file to run,
or save it as a .txt file and drag-and-drop it into one of the exe files in
C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey.
Download link here:
AutoHotkey
http://ahkscript.org/

Also you would need to download Acc.ahk and put it here:
C:\Program Files\AutoHotkey\Lib.
Instructions and download link here:
Acc library (MSAA) and AccViewer download links - AutoHotkey Community
https://autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=26201

Hope that helps.

Note: this is the sort of script that can potentially break, if VLC
do a radical update at some point, but that can be easily readjusted
to work correctly again.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you  using? 
As far as I can remember on linux VLC (like mplayer) outputs all the time to the console how far the movie is played and also i it is paused.

In this case you could simply redirect this output to the input of your java program which reads it and waits for the "pause" marker. than reads back the last time-stamp.

There might be a better way, but this seams to be the easiest way, without any further research, to me.

Comment: I'm using windows, haven't really used ubuntu, but will check it out, thanks for the suggestion. And how to access that console output in ubuntu, I mean should I start running the console along with my client or does it run in background itself?

Comment: @wannabe everthing: Sorry I'm not a windows guy. In linux you would do something like this `vlc exaample.mpg 2> java MyProgram` to start the video in the console and redirect the output to the java program.